# $SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id gives undefined for Guest user

Tags: lightning, lightning-community

I just stumbled upon something while using `$A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id")` to get current user id in lightning component.
 `$A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id")` returns Id only if user is logged in and is not guest user. In case of Guest user, undefined is returned. Is that an intended behavior or just another bug in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of how we can access Guest User IDs via Apex, VF and SOQL... I would categorize this as an oversight or bug. I have seen no documentation stating this was intentional. Ultimately, observing how this works in other areas of the platform lends weight to viewing this as an oversight or bug.

Facts:

> - Apex: UserInfo.getUserId() returns an ID for Guest User.
> - VF page: {!$User.Id} returns an ID for Guest User.
> - SOQL: Guest User is first-class User in User table. Session or not, they have an ID that can be queried like any other User.

Answer (score 3):

Guest user in Salesforce is intended user for Salesforce Sites without the need to login. Here are few features related to [guest user](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006778&language=en_US&type=1)

> Guest user licenses are required for force.com sites. EE/UE orgs are
>   allowed to create up to 25 sites hence the 25 guest user licenses.

1. Each site has a special user with a user type called guest user type
2. Guest users have no password, no role and have no API access on their profile.
3. You can't login or do client side api call (only within apex code).
4. There is no session for guest browsing
5. Each guest user (site) has a unique profile (public access settings)
6. These profiles are associated to guest user licenses which give the ability to read/create on standard objects and full CRUD on
   custom objects.  However, by default no CRUD is given.  Admins needs
   to enable the right level of access based on their flow
7. We advise private sharing for the objects that are enabled for sites
8. Guest user licenses can't be used for any other purposes other than Force.com Sites.

Since, the guest users have no session/login information, therefore it is likely the reason why the method `$A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id")` returns undefined.

Comment: Calling UserInfo.getUserId() on Guest User DOES RETURN the User ID of the User.

Comment: How do you reason that $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id") = undefined is intended behavior? I don't follow. A Guest User is definitely limited, but is a true User and exists in the User table with an ID just like any other User. We can access a Guest User's Id in SOQL. We can access a Guest User's Id via UserInfo. I don't follow your logic.

Comment: also... VF page context {!$User.Id} DOES RETURN the User ID of the Guest User. You should correct your answer...

Comment: @krigi thanks for pointing out. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

After Spring 21' release, it seems $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id") is not returning undefined anymore byt the ID of the Guest User.